# VSCode not showing expected data type when hover

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to understand how React Proptypes and Typescript are working but I have the following problem : I'm trying to using the same code than this [page](https://amanhimself.dev/blog/prop-types-in-react-and-typescript/) but I don't have the same result. VSCode seems to infer the type of `color` as `any` while I defined it as `string` in the `propTypes`.

My code :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// A component that accepts "color" prop
function FavoriteColor({ color }) {
  return <h2>My favorite Color is {color}</h2>;
}

FavoriteColor.propTypes = {
  color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

// Parent component
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FavoriteColor />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My result :
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An0az.png)

My expectation is to have the type `Proptypes.string`.

Comment: proptypes are different from types from ts, proptypes you will see an error in your development mode in the console, while TS is just a diff story

Comment: Thanks @aleEspinosaM , I understood that but why in the example the screenshot shows that vscode displays the Proptypes when hovering the component ? Because I don't have that with my vscode.